# Finding max with multiple criteria

Tags: python, max, nested-lists

I have a series of nested lists:

```
list1=[[10,5],[8,2],[12,10],[5,7],[12,11],[7,2],[5,3],[11,12]]
```

I need to return the `max` list, using the first element of each list as a key - if there are two or more elements that match this condition, I need to return the one with the larger second element - (i.e, `[12,11]`, not `[12,10]`).

I have used `max(list1,key=lambda x:x[0]))`, but this only returns the first element that matches - `[12,10]`.

Comment: How about `max(list1)` ?

Comment: `max(list1)` gives you your answer (`[12, 11]`), does it not?..

Comment: Yes, it does! Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In python there is already inbuilt max() function for list

code:

```
list1=[[10,5],[8,2],[12,10],[5,7],[12,11],[7,2],[5,3],[11,12]]

print(max(list1))
```

output:

```
[12, 11]
```

you can find list of inbuilt function here
[link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_functions.asp)